# SAS not identifying string variable value

Tags: string, sas

I am writing some if then statements to change a string variable value from one to another but it is not recognizing some of them. I tried using the trim function to remove leading and trailing spaces but still not working. Any ideas why that may be the case?

if proddesc ="CCCC -CCCC CC-CCC" then prod = "th_ccc_ccc";

Comment: Very hard to help you on this without an example that shows it failing to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

`trim()` only removes trailing blanks.  `strip()` removes both leading and trailing blanks.

```
if strip(proddesc) ="CCCC -CCCC CC-CCC" then prod = "th_ccc_ccc";
```

If that doesn't work, add data to your question showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the length on prod.  The following works so if you're still having a problem you'll need to provide more information:

```
data test;
 length prod $10;
 proddesc = "CCCC -CCCC CC-CCC"; 
 prod = "x";
 if proddesc ="CCCC -CCCC CC-CCC" then prod = "th_ccc_ccc";
run;
```